# Sorting in Elasticsearch based on Multiple indices

Tags: mongodb, sorting, elasticsearch

I need to perform sorting on Elasticsearch documents...

I have one index created for MongoDB collections 'products', which have price and product ratings in it.

I have another collection 'product_hits' in which I am save one record (product_id, IP etc.)  on every click of particular product by user. Now I want to sort product documents on by considering Product hit count (maybe which I can get through aggregation), price and product rating. 
In short I want to rank all the products based on price and popularity as other sites does.

How can I achieve this in elasticsearch?

I gone though scripting of elasticsearch and I am able to sort on price and product rating..... but I didn't find anything useful in which we can perform sort based on multiple indices.
is it possible?? or do I have  to sort all records on my own through coding?

I am using play framework.

I hope this question can be understood... Its complex..!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "sort based on multiple indices"? If it's sorting after the index name, this is possible with `"sort": [
    {
      "_index": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]`.

Comment: I want to access data in one script file from an index named 'product_index' and another index named 'product_hits_index' in one query.. is it possible?? Where I have 'product_id' which matches relation between both schema.

Comment: If you think about ES as a relational database where `product_id` belongs to both `product_index` and to `product_hits_index` then you are thinking wrong. That's not how ES works.

Comment: so is there any workaround for achieving this? Any other way?

Comment: You need to re-think your mapping and the data structure. Usually ES likes flat, denormalized data structures, but it also offers parent/child relationships (in the same index, not between two indices) and nested documents.

Comment: okkk....!! thank you @Andrei... maybe I should apply ranking in coding then....after fetching documents from elasticsearch...! Thanks for information..!